# virtualbox - connect from one vm to another

Tags: networking, virtualbox

In one VM, I have a Win XP machine that has a service listening on 0.0.0.0:10000
I can connect from the Win XP to this service, but I have another VM (CentOS) that I would like to connect. When I try to connect from my CentOS, it says connection refused. How can I connect to the service on the Win XP from my other VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use bridged networking as opposed to NAT. This makes each of your VMs NICs appear as if they are actual hardware. Once a DHCP server assigns each VM a private IP address, communication between them and the rest of your local network should be greatly simplified.

Comment: The connection still gets refused, although I can see it from netstat on my CentOS

Comment: I don't see it in netstat anymore after reboot. I'm still on bridged adapter.

Comment: @user3893623 Do you have access to the DHCP server you are using? If so, check if they are being assigned private IP addresses.

Comment: Fixed, icmp requests were disabled.